# Reading parquet file and removing certain rows

Tags: python, dataframe, parquet

I have a parquet file which contains operating hours and special codes (error codes and so on) and I read it with python to a data frame. Everytime the code 1.5.30 appears it means, that a job is started and it is followed by the operating hours. I need to calculate the total operating hours during a job. The problem is, that sometimes 1.5.30 is followed by only one value for operating hours and sometimes 1.5.30 is followed by 1.5.30 again. If it looks like this (of course there is more above and below, this is just for understanding):

| object_value |
| --- |
| ... |
| 365640 |
| 365641 |
| 365642 |
| 1.5.30 |
| 365643 |
| **1.5.30** |
| 365693 |
| 1.5.30 |
| 365694 |
| 365695 |
| 365696 |
| ... |

I need to remove the bold 1.5.30 in the middle so I can at least perform some calculation. All values are stored in the file as strings. I also already filtered the whole data frame to only display the desired values. The filtering is based on another column where specific object_ids belong to these object_values.

I already tried it with finding the correct indices but I haven't come far. For the case that there a two consecutive values I managed to find a solution with the indices, but I couldn't come up with anything that solves this problem.

Comment: when you say python dataframe, which lib exactly are you using ?

Comment: I just read it with the provided pandas function:
`import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet('example_fp.parquet', engine='fastparquet')`